# equivalent of “~” in rpy2?

Tags: python, r, dataframe, rpy2

Simple question that I can't seem to find the answer to. How would I get an attribute of an R object in rpy2? For example, what's the equivalent of the R code: y~x in rpy2?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that object attributes and `~` are two different things.

Regarding `~`, is it used to create formula objects. The corresponding section of the rpy2 documentation is here:
https://rpy2.github.io/doc/v3.3.x/html/robjects_formulae.html